# Using SharePointPnPCoreOnline with Azure Function(v1)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-dev-pnp, azure-functions, nuget

I am creating my first Azure Function(V1) with SharePointPnPCoreOnline package and Visual Studio 2019/2017. When I created a function project without SharePointPnPCoreOnline its working without any error.

But when I added SharePointPnPCoreOnline its started giving me warning message like below

> NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint:
>   Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4 requires Microsoft.Data.OData (=
>   5.6.4) but version Microsoft.Data.OData 5.8.4 was resolved. NU1107: Version conflict detected for Newtonsoft.Json. Install/reference
>   Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1 directly to project CRB.Functions to resolve
>   this issue.   Functions -> SharePointPnPCoreOnline 3.18.2002 ->
>   Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.1)   CRB.Functions ->
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24 -> Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1).
>   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Functions'.

Upon my research I came across with below post from elio where the solution has been suggested for this problem.

https://www.eliostruyf.com/using-the-latest-sharepoint-pnp-core-online-dependency-in-your-azure-functions/

Based on recommendation from this post, solution to this problem is to install "Newtonsoft.Json" package before installing "SharePointPnPCoreOnline".

When I install "Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1" got below warning.

> NU1608    Detected package version outside of dependency constraint:
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24 requires Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1)
>   but version Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1 was resolved.

And now I am stuck because I added a reference "Newtonsoft.Json" to my function v1 project with warnings. Should I ignore this warning and continue?

[image]

**2/21/2020**

After having a discussion @Derek with I have also tested this with Azure Function V2 and Azure Function V3 and got warnings in both scenarios.

github repo https://github.com/ravick4u/AzureFunV1WithPnP

**Errors with Azure Function V2**

> Warning   NU1608  Detected package version outside of dependency
>   constraint: Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4 requires
>   Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.6.4) but version Microsoft.Data.OData 5.8.4
>   was resolved.     1
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
>   2.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel 6.1.7600.16394' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM
>   16.1.19724.12000' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions 1.2.4'
>   was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'SharePointPnPCoreOnline 3.18.2002' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

**Errors with Azure Function V3**

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
>   2.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel 6.1.7600.16394' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM
>   16.1.19724.12000' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.
>
> Warning   NU1701  Package 'SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions 1.2.4'
>   was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the NewtonSoft reference. Azure Functions uses its own Newtonsoft dependency internally, and any explicit references to it will break the project.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I am adding NewtonSoft because I am unable to add SharePointPnPCoreOnline. without independent NewtonSoft I can not add SharePointPnPCoreOnline

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I've experienced this before but not recently. You might try updating your Visual Studio Azure tools. I'm on VS2019 with the latest Azure dev workload. Good luck!

Comment: I am on VS2019(v16.4.5) which is the latest one and having this issue. Are you also on the same version? Is it possible for you to do a quick test?(1. Create Azure Function V1 and Add SharePointPnPCoreOnline reference)

Comment: Yep, I did it and it worked for me. AZ Function tools ver. 16.4.460.23317| PnP Version 3.18.2002 | Newtonsoft included dependency ver. 11.0.2 | VS 2019  v.16.4.4

Comment: What kind of trigger are you using? I used an HTTP trigger.

Comment: I am using Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.4.460.23317 | PNP 3.18.2002 | NewTonSoft v11.02(triedv12.0.1 as well) | VS2019 16.4.5. And yes I am using HTTP Trigger.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if this warning message can be ignored or not?

Comment: Just now I installed a new version of VS2019 on a fresh machine and still having the same issue. I can pass on the sample project that I created to you if that is ok.

Comment: can you please let me know which version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package you have?

Comment: 1.0.29. Put a solution in github - a basic implementation to repro the issue - put a link here and I'll try to run it.

Comment: That means you are using AzureFunction V2. With V2 you don't have to add Newtonsoft.Json reference because Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 already have a reference of Newtonsoft v11.0.2. I have created a solution with V1, V2, and V3 and uploaded it to Github. I am getting a warning message with all versions. I will update my question with messages for V2 and V3. https://github.com/ravick4u/AzureFunV1WithPnP

Comment: Came across with another post here which discuss the same issue https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262808/officedevpnp-core-used-in-azure-function-v1-alternatives and https://www.sjlewis.com/2018/12/13/newtonsoft-version-conflicts-with-azure-function-pnp-sites-core/ as per the blog warning message will be there